# NSPasteboard with RTF/RTFD Changing Font

Tags: cocoa, nspasteboard

I'm working on a utility that pastes images with text. So far the best way I've found to do this was using `NSPasteboard` and encapsulating the images and text in an RTFD data stream. The problem I'm having is that even though I have no font attributes (I have checked) every time I paste copied code into a document it changes the font to 'Helvetica size 12'. Is it possible to force paste the text and images without changing the font?

```
void copyData() {

    let pboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    pboard.clearContents()

    let str = NSMutableAttributedString()

    for im in images {
        let a = NSTextAttachment()
        a.image = im

        let s = NSAttributedString(attachment: a)
        str.appendAttributedString(s)
    }

    //now I have an rtf with a whole bunch of images
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, str.length)

    if let d = str.RTFDFromRange(range, documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSPlainTextDocumentType]) {
        pboard.setData(d, forType: NSPasteboardTypeRTFD)
    }

    pboard.writeObjects(images)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Cocoa NSAttributedString Pasting Changes Font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915530/cocoa-nsattributedstring-pasting-changes-font)